# How can I get the coordinates of my mouse?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script that will repeatedly write my mouse coordinates to an element as I navigate with it. But I'm not sure how to detect information from the mouse. Some one wanna point me in the right direction?

`document.getElementById("coords").innerHTML = crdX + ", " + crdY`

http://jsfiddle.net/7pj9gpvn/

EDIT: My question is not a duplicate of the proposed question because the proposed question is concerned with the loop aspect of the same problem, whereas mine is concerned with the 'event handling' aspect. I did read and attempt to ascertain the information I needed from that question, but as I am a beginner, I found their code difficult to read.

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach a MouseEvent and the event object passed to the handler will give you the coordinates. Attach it to the document if you want to track the movement everywhere. `clientX` and `clientY` properties give you local coordinates while `screenX` and `screenY` give you global coordinates.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/7pj9gpvn/4/

HTML:

```
<p id="coords"></p>
<p id="coords2"></p>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove',
    function (event) {
        var para = document.getElementById('coords');
        para.textContent = event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY;
        var para2 = document.getElementById('coords2');
        para2.textContent = event.screenX + ", " + event.screenY;
    }
);
```

Feel free to read up on it yourself too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove

Answer (score 3):

Try This works on all browser

http://jsfiddle.net/7hxtLqd4/

```
<html>

<body>
            <form name="mShow">
        <input type="text" name="MX" value="0" size="4"> X
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="MY" value="0" size="4"> Y
        <br>
    </form>

    <script language="JavaScript1.2">

        var IE = document.all ? true : false

        if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)

        document.onmousemove = getMouse;

        var tempX = 0
        var tempY = 0


        function getMouse(e) {
            if (IE) { 
                tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
            } else { 
                tempX = e.pageX
                tempY = e.pageY
            }

            if (tempX < 0) {
                tempX = 0
            }
            if (tempY < 0) {
                tempY = 0
            }
           // ADD TEMP VALUE FOR FIELDS
            document.mShow.MX.value = tempX
            document.mShow.MY.value = tempY
            return true
        }


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```